# Knockoutjs: dynamic content and applyBindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am "dynamically" populating my page like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ContainerTemplate">
  <span data-bind="template: {
                     name: contentTemplate,
                     data: contentData }"></span>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="fooTemplate">
  <span data-bind="text: barAttribute"></span>
</script>

<button data-bind="click: complete">complete</button>

Hello
<span data-bind="template: { name: 'ContainerTemplate', foreach: myContents }"></span>
!
```

ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
    myContents: ko.observableArray([]),
    complete: function() {
        viewModel.myContents.push({
            contentTemplate:'fooTemplate',
            contentData:{barAttribute:'world'}});
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

A particularity is that template names are dynamic. It seems to work like this (you can try it on http://jsfiddle.net/hPQNx/ ), but I wonder if I'm doing things correctly. Some template features like root or parent don't seem to be working.

Should I manually re-call applyBindings at some point ? I have seen this must be done on the related DOM nodes, but how can I access those nodes in my setup ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a property to your view model and showed how you can add a root property and reference it with `$root` and `$parent` can work here in this fiddle.

```js
var viewModel = {
    a: ko.observable('foo'),
    myContents: ko.observableArray([]),
    complete: function() {
        viewModel.myContents.push({
            contentTemplate: 'fooTemplate',
            b: 'goo',
            contentData: {
                barAttribute: 'world'
            }
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="ContainerTemplate">
  <span data-bind="template: {
                     name: contentTemplate,
                     data: contentData }"></span>
</script>
      
<script type="text/html" id="fooTemplate">
  <span data-bind="text: barAttribute"></span>
  <div data-bind="text: $root.a"></div>
  <div data-bind="text: $parent.b"></div>
</script>

<button data-bind="click: complete">complete</button>

Hello
<span data-bind="template: { name: 'ContainerTemplate', foreach: myContents }"></span>
!
```

Comment: Indeed. I'm sorry for not having tested that far in the fiddle. My assumption was that it was because of the dynamic template, but could this be because I have an old version of Knockoutjs (1.2.1) ? Is there a versionned documentation, or a functional changelog where I could check that ?

Comment: 1.2.1 does not support $root, $parent, $parents (or $data outside of jQuery Templates).  These context variables were added in 2.0.

Comment: @Gnurfos - that's correct. Those features were not added til KO 2.0.0. There were few breaking changes in KO 2. The only one that bit me at all was that in previous version the event handler received the DOM event object as the first parameter. In KO v2, the event handler receives the model as the first parameter, and the DOM event object as the second parameter. You will need to change any KO code that uses the DOM event object  to account for it as the second parameter.

// KO v1.2
myViewModel.myEventHandler = function(evt)

// KO v2
myViewModel.myEventHandler = function(data, evt)

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting the answer, since both your comments answered my problem. Even if my original question was irrelevant :)